# WLST Script for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, wlst

I m trying to find some kind of script tool for monitoring my tomcat server and applications/interfaces deployed within the server.
Is there are tool similar to WLST available in weblogic ?

I will be preparing the web-application , which will get the details of different servers and display it on the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope not yet available like WLST Vaibhava, I would suggest you look for JMX remote monitoring thru Zabbix an open source monitoring tool, which uses very light processes with Master/Agent architecture with pretty UI. There are some templates for Tomcat JMX find here :

1. [[JMX zabbix template]](https://gist.github.com/hgomez/3209196)[1](https://gist.github.com/hgomez/3209196)
2. [JMX Config settings](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/cookbook/specific)

Comment: THanks. I found a very useful tool - javamelody which does all these things beforehand. Just plugit and use it.